# Javascript String replace isn't replacing my parameter

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have the following string:

```
"Write the conjugate of each radical expression.\n\n**(a)** `$2\\sqrt{3} - 4$`\n\n**(b)** `$\\sqrt{3} +\\sqrt{2}$`\n\n**(c)** `$-2\\sqrt{3} - \\sqrt{2}$`\n\n**(d)** `$3\\sqrt{3} + \\sqrt{2} $`\n\n**(e)** `$\\sqrt{2} - \\sqrt{5}$`\n\n**(f)** `$-\\sqrt{5} + 2\\sqrt{2}$`"
```

And I have the following function to go through a string and replace substrings:

```
var changeString = function(markdownStr) {
     return markdownStr.replace(/`/g, "").replace("$ ", "$").replace(" $", "$");
};
```

The result I get is that it replaces some of the conditions (the `), but it didn't work for the last replace condition (" $").

Here is the output:

```
Write the conjugate of each radical expression. **(a)**$2\sqrt{3} - 4$ **(b)** $\sqrt{3} +\sqrt{2}$ **(c)** $-2\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}$ **(d)** $3\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} $ **(e)** $\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{5}$ **(f)** $-\sqrt{5} + 2\sqrt{2}$
```

You can see for the (d) option, it still outputs as `$3\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} $` but I expected it to be `$3\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$`.

What is going on and why isn't it replacing it?

Here is a codepen example:
https://codepen.io/jae_kingsley/pen/MWyWZbN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

> If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the
> first instance of the value will be replaced

So you should probably use regular expressions for all replaces, not just the first one.  Don't forget you'll have to escape the `$`:

```
.replace(/\s\$/g, '$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing you code to following will work as it accounts for any `$` with space before or after or none. So it will match  `$`, `$` , `$`,      `$` etc.

```
var changeString = function(markdownStr) {
  return markdownStr.replace(/`/g, "").replace(/\s*\$\s*/g, '$');
};
```